# how to add string to cuckoo filter?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use cuckoo filter code from github link
https://github.com/efficient/cuckoofilter

whenever I'm using data type string it gave me error
mycode:

```
cuckoofilter::CuckooFilter<string, 12> filter(total_items);
```

but every time I run the code this error appears

```
error: no match for call to ‘(const cuckoofilter::TwoIndependentMultiplyShift) (const std::_cxx11::basic_string&)’ 68 | const uint64_t hash = hasher(item);
```

on following line

https://github.com/efficient/cuckoofilter/blob/master/src/cuckoofilter.h#L68

Answer (score 0):

In your filter declaration, you're using the type std::string; expecting std::string to be the ItemType in
`template <typename ItemType, ...> class CuckooFilter { }`

However, the hash function, `TwoIndependentMultiplyShift` requires a `uint64_t` type key. The method is in the file https://github.com/efficient/cuckoofilter/blob/master/src/hashutil.h.

Because of the type mismatch, a runtime error occurs. The types are not constrained during compilation time under old C++ standards. Therefore, you do not see any compile time errors.

To resolve your issue you might have to use a hash function which supports std::string or use a compatible ItemType.

C++20 introduces [concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) to restrict template parameters and will be helpful in restricting the types that can be used as template parameters. With this the error will be evident during compile time.